# Accessing sexually explicit materials on twitter using wifi network at office

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection

Need your help.

I opened a twitter account containing sexually explicit materials using my own iphone while I was out of office and when I went back to the office, I didnt realize that my iphone was connected to company's wifi network (fyi, the wifi had previously required me to have a username n password to log in) while my twitter was still running.

My question is: can IT Dept see what I opened on twitter app? 
If they can, will they really find potential violations? 
What sanctions would I probaby get? Thank you.

---

Thank you for your answers. Actually my company requires employees' corporate username (and password) to log in to the wifi, therefore my wifi username will be easily associated with my real name/corporate profile. I actually still played with my twitter (which contains explicit materials) a few minutes and left it idle for about an hour before i realized that it's connected to a wifi network instead of 3G i used while out of office. Im really afraid now that IT will call me for this. I heard that twitter information is encrypted. Is that true? In what condition will IT open that? - Joe

Comment: The traffic is most likely logged - but combed through, doubt it. Depends on what stuff you IT uses/ how strict the company is on it. I doubt they will see it. They already didn't block Twitter. As far as "sanctions" go, whatever is in the company regulations you signed is what you are susceptible to. I doubt one link'll do you in though. It will most likely go unnoticed. Probably.

Comment: I am sure the information has been logged.  But unless the IT staff has a reason to "view" internet logs specifically for you doubtful it would be found.  Also, if the network is open, it can be done, it would be difficult to tie the "violator" device to a specific individual.

Comment: "Can my IT Dept see what I opened on twitter app?' - Depends on the network configuration.  You should go ask your IT Department this question.

Comment: @joe People post all kind of stuff on social networking sites. So either your IT would not allow you to access them in office at all or would not care monitoring them so tightly to find out what kind of material are you really accessing in these sites, unless you are not accessing them for too long and they get alerted or somebody reports you of doing unprofessional or unethical. If this was me, I wouldn't worry so much.

Comment: We can't really evaluate the situation unless you post some sample images.  ONLY KIDDING.

Answer (score 1):

Good news!
Twitter uses HTTPS! The IT-department can see that you have have some traffic to twitter, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like, You had opened it on a different network, left it open and joined another network. The actual data open on the phone was retrieved on a different network.  Unless the page got refreshed, or you loaded more explicit material while on the company network you should be fine.  They can't see what is already open, they can only see what was opened. The explicit data you saw on your phone was already downloaded to your phone and you are seeing a local copy of it.

I don't know how twitter communicates back to it's servers, but it could be making pingbacks to the server saying that you have a certain post/profile open, although you're not actually reloading the entire profile again, in the network traffic, the profile/post number may be visible.  The admin would have to manually visit that post/profile to see for themselves if it is explicit, and they would probably need a reason or suspicion to go and do that.

When I block wireless users in corporate networks, I am never able to determine who that user is unless the device has a hostname configured (such as `Joe's iPhone`).  The best I could do is block the MAC address, look at the AP in which the device is connected to, and walk around that area to see if I can spot anything.